# Vim: Issue normal-mode commands in user-defined command

Tags: vim

I'm certain this will have been asked somewhere, but I can't for the life of me find it, and it's not in the [Defining command-line commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2) section of the Vim documentation.

I want to create a user-defined command which will insert the word `foo` before the current word.

<sup>(Note: I want it to be a function because I don't trust myself to remember *yet another* shortcut key. I know how to do it with `noremap`...)</sup>

In my `.vimrc` I add:

```
command AddFoo bifoo<esc>w
```

But when I type `:AddFoo` I get `Not an editor command: bifoow`.

Is it possible to have a function which issues normal mode commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:normal` Ex command allows to issue arbitrary normal mode commands.

```
command AddFoo normal! bifoo<esc>w
```

If you want to interpolate expressions etc., you need to use `:execute`; I'll just show your example again with the use of `:help key-notation`:

```
command AddFoo execute "normal! bifoo\<esc>w"
```

The `!` after `:normal` prevents the use of custom mappings, like `:noremap` (vs `:map`).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you get the difference between a command and a function.

The right hand side of a command definition is supposed to be *at least* one Ex command like `write` or `bnext`:

```
command! Foo update | tabnext
```

You can call a function:

```
command! Bar call Bar()
```

or execute a normal mode macro:

```
command! Baz normal ciw"<C-r>""
```

See `:help :normal`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple to get what you want, you just need to switch to normal mode to make your changes:

```
command AddFoo normal bifoo<esc>w
```